# Performing on change in total number of rows of an HTML table in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to perform action on change in count of rows of an HTML table in javascript. Say, If total rows is increased by adding rows , I need to show a Div. Is there any event for HTML table that I can use.

Thanks in advance.
Ravi Kumar

Comment: can you not add an event to what ever is adding rows ???

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I can add event to that but the problem is that I don't want by div to be visible on click of that button as click may result to unsuccessful operation. So my requirement is to show div only when row count increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DOMNodeInserted` event for notification about DOM changes:

Ref: http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
  var item = event.target;
  if (item.tagName == 'TR' && item.parentNode.getAttribute('id') == 'your-table-id') { 
    // ... event handling code ...
  }
});
```

*NOTE*: The above is untested code. You might need to debug it before it works completely.

Comment: I think only older IE versions have a problem. Should be fine on other browsers. But then, you can't expect things like these to work correctly in IE., can you? :-)

Comment: It worked. I am getting alert messages on adding rows to table. But I don't know why it is showing alert message on removing rows ( I don't want it to work in that way).

Comment: @techfoobar  Thank you. I found the problem. It was in my table. GWT Based screen is re-creating new rows even on remove of a single row. The reason is that. Thank you